# Jenkins build became unstable - what am I supposed to do?

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just released a new version of an existing package.  Before the release I ran the prerelease test successfully.

Now I got an email from the ROS Buildfarm with the subject: "Jenkins build became unstable: [...]"

**edit:**
Here is the link contained in the email: http://build.ros.org/job/Idev__innok_heros_gazebo__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/3/changes

What am I supposed to do? Is this critical?

Regards,
Sabrina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226340/jenkins-build-became-unstable---what-am-i-supposed-to-do?/) by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-02-11**:
If you include the link to the actual job in the question you might get a more helpful answer.

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2016-02-11**:
thanks for the hint - > I added the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `devel` job is building your source code when you commit any changes to the branch specified in the `source` section of rosdistro (after some delay, commonly checking once every hour).

If you read through the console output (http://build.ros.org/job/Idev__innok_heros_gazebo__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/3/consoleFull) you will find the section where the tests are being run (http://build.ros.org/job/Idev__innok_heros_gazebo__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/3/consoleFull#console-section-17). The test checking the roslaunch file fails with a stacktrace.

Based on that you will find the test results at the end which say:

```
The total number of tests for this category exceeds the specified 'unstable' threshold value.
Setting the build status to UNSTABLE
```

That's why the build was marked as `unstable` and you received a notification email. You can also see the summary of all tests here: http://build.ros.org/job/Idev__innok_heros_gazebo__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/3/testReport/

Now to reason *why* the test might fail. The stacktrace says: `rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: gazebo_ros` My first guess would be that your launch file uses something from the `gazebo_ros` package but since your package.xml file doesn't declare a dependency on that package it is not available on the build farm. That also means if someone if installing your Debian package and tried to run the launch file it would fail in a similar way. Therefore you will likely have to add a run dependency on `gazebo_ros` to make this test pass and the Debian package usable.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2016-02-11**:
Thank you, now I see. The problem is exactly as you said: I removed run deps concerning gazebo from package.xml because this resolves in system dependencies of Gazebo2 in the resulting debian package. But I need Gazebo6 in order get a correctly running robot model with this package.

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2016-02-11**:
In fact this is related with my other question: http://answers.ros.org/question/226336/howto-release-a-package-with-system-dependency-ros-indigo-gazebo6-ros/?comment=226345#post-id-226345

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2016-02-11**:
Can I ignore the fact that the build is unstable until I found a way to include gazebo6 as run dep? Or could anything be harmed as long as the build is unstable?

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2016-03-03**:
As a workaround I removed the line `roslaunch_add_file_check(launch)` from the CMakeLists.txt. The build is stable now. But users will have to install `ros-indigo-gazebo6` and `ros-indigo-gazebo6-plugins` manually to be able to run the launch files.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The email usually contains an email with the jenkins link to the build logs. Check if it's your fault or it is something that needs fixing. If in doubt write to the ros-release mailing list.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2